# Connecting MS SQL server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, localhost

I'm using MS SQL server 2012 on my homeserver.
I can connect to the server using localhost but not with my ISP ip adress if I'm at home. How can I local connect to SQL using my ISP ip adres when I'm at home.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to connect via a public address (the IP of your ISP), you need to ensure that you have an inbound connection through your router opened on port 1433 which is what SQL is answering on.

Q: Are you sure that you want to expose SQL directly to a public connection like that? You open yourself up to hacking and exploits.